# Grep: Excluding a specific folder using

Tags: linux, grep

Say our folder structure looks like this:

```
/app
/app/data
...
/app/secondary
/app/secondary/data
```

I want to recursively search `/app/data` but I do not want to search `/app/secondary/data`.

From within the app folder, what would my grep command look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='secondary/data' PATTERN data
```

Comment: Only for gnu grep version >=2.5.1a

Comment: so how to do it prior to gnu grep 2.5.1a ?

Comment: `--exclude-dir='secondary/data' is redundant here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

## Why the accepted answer is wrong

The accepted answer by @seamus is wrong because `grep -r --exclude-dir=<glob>` matches against *base names* which by definition can't contain slashes (slashes turn it into a no-op effectively as no base name will match).

From [GNU Grep Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection):

> **--exclude-dir=glob**
>
> ...When searching **recursively**, skip any subdirectory whose **base name** matches **glob**...

## Why the question is probably wrong

I think the OP's directory structure doesn't represent the problem well because because if one has...

```
.
├── app
    ├── data
    └── secondary
        └── data
```

... and the current directory is `app` one can simply do:

```
> grep -r <search-pattern> data
```

It will not search the `secondary` folder as its not inside `data`.

## What the intended question might be

Given directory structure with nested `data` folders how to look in the top-level `data` but not in the nested folders.

```
.
└── data
    ├── file.txt
    ├── folder1
    │   └── folder2
    │       ├── data
    │       │   └── file.txt
    │       └── file.txt
    └── folder3
        ├── data
        │   └── file.txt
        └── file.txt
```

## What the answer would be

```
> grep -r --exclude-dir='data' <search-pattern> data/*
```

Note the `*` at the end. If omitted the top-level `data` folder won't be searched neither.

Comment: `matches against base names` important to know here. After looking at a few SO answers, this was the only one that pointed that out